# Adding particular column as foreign key in rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-migrations

I have two tables, `Article` and `Article_metadata`.

I added reference and foreign key between these two tables. But rails will some how takes `article_id` (id column of Article table) as foreign key.

But i want another column in Article table (`Article_uuid`)  as my foreign key. How do i do it ?

This is how i'm doing it now. In create `Article_metadata` migration file:

```
add_reference :article_metadata, :article, foreign_key: true
```

Answer (score 3):

In your ArticleMetaData class, add a custom foreign key to the belongs_to declaration. Here's an example:

```
class ArticleMetaData < ActiveRecord::Base
  table_name "Article_metadata"
  belongs_to :article, foreign_key: "article_uuid"
end
```

add_reference actually creates a new column and index, but it sounds like your columns already exist so you wouldn't need new ones.

To reference the meta data from the article, modify your article model to reference the same foreign_key field:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Tell ActiveRecord which column is the primary key (id by default)
  self.primary_key = 'uuid'

  # Tell the relationship which field on the meta_data table to use to match this table's primary key
  has_one :meta_data, foreign_key: "article_uuid", class_name: "ArticleMetaData"

end
```

Comment: Hw can i retrieve article metadata for a particular article ? can i do Article.Article_metadata ?

Comment: And the new created foreign key columns defaults to integer datatype, how can i set the datatype to string or varchar ?

Comment: I made an edit to show you how to lookup meta data from the article. Having no idea what your model names actually are, you might need to tweak it a bit, but the rest is good.

Comment: you are awesome, it works. Will this constraint be enforced in database level as well?

Comment: You can set it to by adding an index from a migration. It would look something like: add_index :articles, :uuid, index: true, unique: true

Comment: You may also want to add an index to your meta_data table to make it's lookup a bit faster.

Comment: The constraints works fine in sqllite, but not in MySql though. The foreign key reference to article_uuid, it expects it to be integer, whereas i want it to be string. In the migration, i have added reference like this.  'add_reference :article_metadata, :article, primary_key: 'article_uuid', type: :string, foreign_key: true '   The error i'm getting is 'Mysql2::Error: Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes: ALTER TABLE `article_metadata` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_rails_2850043a48`. And it tries to reference article_id instead of article_uuid